# Test of a binary endpoint in longitudinal design

Tags: binary-data, cox-model, clinical-trials, cochran-mantel-haenszel

Suppose I conduct a randomized, double-blind, placebo-controlled trial. I follow-up patients at weeks 4, 8, and 12. My primary endpoint is "treatment response" by week 12. In this case, even if there is a relapse at week 12, they would have been considered a success if response was achieved at weeks 4 and 8. My primary endpoint is treatment response by week 12.

Patients may drop out prior to week 12 visit. As such, it makes sense to consider "responders" as such if they meet response criteria at either week 4 or week 8 visit. However, for those lost to follow-up, even without informative censoring, we can envision a form of bias of considering them non-responders (because the week 12 visit may have been a response).

Two analyses come to mind:

- the Cochrane Mantel-Haenszel test stratified by study timepoint.
- the Cox proportional hazards model with Efron method for ties

My questions are:

1. What are the necessary assumptions to ensure the significance test from either test is consistent for treatment difference at 12 weeks?
2. Are there any predictive tools that yield imputations which are known to be consistent with the previous tests? For instance, if the Cox model is used to estimate the baseline hazard function and generate multiply imputed endpoints conditioned on the duration of follow-up, will this be effectively the same as the default test of the hazard ratio?